# Javascript Filter a list & return matched item from it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better way to write the below JS code for filtering & returning item from an array;

```
myArray.forEach(function(x) {
    if (x.id === y.id) {
        row = x;
    }
})
```

I am open to using jquery

Comment: it depends on the data. please include `myArray` and `y`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: [**Code Review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you’re trying to achieve… what is `y` and `row` and what is the expected result?

Comment: is `id` unique in the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use ES6 features, there is an array method `.find` that you could use like so:

```
const row = myArray.find(x => x.id === y.id)
```

Comment: But `find` is not exactly the same. The OP’s code will set `row` to the _last_ found `x`, not the _first_ one, like `find` will.

Comment: @Xufox, nice spotted.

Comment: myArray.reverse().find... :p

Answer (score 0):

find will return the first matched item so would be faster in some cases as it will break processing after it has found the first item:

```
row = myArray.find(function(x) {
    return x.id === y.id;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) has a method called `$.inArray(value, array)` it returns the index of the item, or `-1` if not found.

```
var index = $.inArray(y.id, myArray); // Assuming x.id is in myArray
var row = (index != -1) ? myArray[index] : -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need an early exit with ES5, then you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and return `true` if found.

```
myArray.some(function(x) {
    if (x.id === y.id) {
        row = x;
        return true;
    }
});
```